# Query to search for a specific value in a db column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to know whether there are any '0's in the `issues_status` column of the `issues` table. The issues_status column store values: '0' & '1'. I guess a query find the count of 0's would give me the required result. May i know how to accomplish this.

**issues** Table

| issues_id | issues_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: Kindly show the query/codes that you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(issues_status) 
FROM issues 
WHERE issues_status=0
```

Comment: How to write that same query in codeigniter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeigniter but heres a link about that hope it helps (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count)